I am getting a "Bad Request" while login using my nodejs server but i am confused why i am getting this error. I am quite new to nodejs
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(async(email,password,done) => {
   try{
    const user = await User.findOne({email:email})
    if(!user){
       return done(null,false,{message:"Invalid email"})
    }
    const isValidPassword =await User.comparePassword(password)
    if(!isValidPassword){
        return done(null,false,{message:"Incorrect password"})
    }
    console.log("Valid user");
    return done(null, user);
   }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
   return done(err);
   }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.render('signup')
})
app.get('/home',passport.authenticate('local'),(req,res) => {
    res.render('home')
})
app.get('/login',(req,res) => {
    res.render('login')
})
app.post('/signup',async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        const newUser = await User.create(req.body);
        res.status(200).redirect('/login');
        console.log("User data saved");
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json("Internal server error")
    }
})
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local'),(req,res) => {
    res.redirect('/home')
})
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})

I tried changing my routes , passport authentication code

where are you getting this "bad request" error? In the browser? what request is "bad"

yes i am getting the bad request on browser while login. /home request is bad

oh, sorry, I meant which line of code you posted gets a bad request error

that is what i am not getting it

i ask chatgpt , it modifies my code by using flash and session and now it is showing another error missing credentials

chatgpt modified your code? how did chatgpt gain access to your code? your code is server code, the error is in the browser ... you haven't shown the browser code ... so, how do you expect to be told what you did wrong?

i mean i provided my code to chatgpt with the error i am facing

So, now you've found that chatgpt is as useless as we are when you don't provide all relevant code (i.e. browser code as well)

In the browser? which line of code you posted gets a bad request error the error is in the browser ... you haven't shown the browser code you don't provide all relevant code (i.e. browser code as well) - address those from my previous comments, and I may be able to

Those might be the reasons of you "Bad Request" error you're encountering:
First, ensure that you have middleware set up to parse the request body properly. In your code, you haven't shown how you're parsing the request body. You might need to use middleware like
express.urlencoded() or express.json() before your routes.
Then, Double-check your Passport configuration to ensure that it's correctly initialized. Ensure that your passport is set up before your route handlers.
Finally, ensure that your User model has a comparePassword method implemented correctly. It seems like you're calling User.comparePassword(password) directly, but you should probably be calling this method on an instance of the User model.
For instance, if you have a method like this in your User model:
.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword) {};
Then, you should call it on an instance of User, not directly on the User model.
